# Product of two non-zero complex numbers equals zero

Tags: complex-numbers

Is it possible for the product of 2 *non-zero* complex numbers to be 0?

Comment: $0$ is complex.

Comment: If neither of the numbers is $0$, then no. The first thought that comes to mind is that the magnitude of the product is the product of the magnitudes, which is nonzero.

Comment: @ElliotG thanks for pointing that out. I revised my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, it is not possible.**

For complex numbers $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ we have that
$$z_1\cdot z_2 = 0 \quad\implies\quad z_1 = 0\quad\text{ or }\quad z_2 = 0.$$

As a hint: non-zero complex numbers have multiplicative inverses.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z_1 = r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $z_2 = r_2e^{i\theta_2}$ then $z_1z_2 = r_1 r_2 e^{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}$. Now $\exp(.)$ is never $0$ so for $z_1z_2$ to be $0$ we need one of $r_1, r_2$ to be $0$. But this immediately implies that one of $z_1,z_2$ have to be $0$. So no.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible. the product of 2 complex number can equal 0 if and only if one of the numbers is zero.
   i.e a.b = 0 where a,b are complex numbers
     Then either a or b is 0

Comment: The question is why